# AngularFire Authentication Access to Google AccessToken

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

Using the [Firebase Web SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin), you can reference the AccessToken as follows:

```
const provider = new auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login');

firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
  var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  // The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;
  // ...
});
```

You can subsequently use the `token` to get more information about your user; for example:

```
public getFirstName(token: string): Observable<string> {
  const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=' + token;

  return this.http.get(url).map(response => {
    return response.json().given_name;
  });
}
```

**Question**: How do you retrieve this access token using the [AngularFire2 protocol](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md)?

```
public loginGoogle() {
  this.af.auth.login().then((authState) => {
    authState.WHERE_IS_IT; // <<<----- 
  })
}
```

Thanks in advance!  // Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [implementation of `login`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/2.0.0-beta.8/src/auth/auth.ts#L99-L105) calls the authentication backend (the SDK) and passes the received [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.UserCredential) to [`authDataToAuthState`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/2.0.0-beta.8/src/auth/auth_backend.ts#L56-L100) - with the `credential` passed as the `providerData`.

`authDataToAuthState` has a switch statement that maps the `credential` to a provider-dependent property. For `google.com`, the credential should be stored in the `google` property:

```ts
case 'google.com':
  authState.google = providerData; // i.e. the credential
  authState.provider = AuthProviders.Google;
  break;
```

Note that the authentication methods are going to be removed from AngularFire2 for the release candidate. There is a discussion regarding that [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/854). Once removed, the SDK is to be used directly for signing in, etc. - which, hopefully, will make things less confusing.